# TextPad won't save class as .java

Tags: java, textpad

In TextPad, I have a class called Document1. I click on file-save as and for "save as type" I click "Java". However, when I hit OK, instead of showing up as Document1.java, it shows up as Document1.txt. Why does it save as a .txt file? And how do I get it to save as a .java file?

Comment: when saving the file, try it withing quotations as such "Document1.java" and then click save.

Answer (score 1):

While saving, select the file type as All Types(*) and name as Document1.java.

Answer (score 1):

`Configure`, `Preferences`, `File Name Filters`

Create a `File Name Filter` for Java

`Description:` can be whatever you want, but the `Wild cards:` should be `*.java`

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the file extension from the folder, replacing the .txt with .java . Make sure to check the "File Name Extensions" box in the veiw tab so you can see the .txt and .java .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following things-

1. Plain Text File Encodings are in Unicode (UTF-8) by going in
   TextEdit > Preference > Open and Save tab.

[Preferences>Open and Save Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/584pt.png)

2. The Format of the file is in Plain Text. You can change this by either going into TextEdit > Preference > New Document tab or going into Format > Make it Plain Text. I advise you to use both ways.
3. Save the file as .txt or anything the first time and then rename it to .java.
   It will give you a warning by asking if you sure want to save the file .java. Just say yes and wallah!!

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN5KS.png)

Can you then run it using the terminal by navigating the path using the `cd` command and running it using `javac [filename]`